# My System Tray Stopped Giving Me The Option To Minimize Visible Notifications

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notification-area

I am using Windows 7 Professional.  My system tray is taking up almost the whole task bar!  The arrow that allows you to hide the running programs into the system tray is just gone.  I have found how to customize the notification area icons, but not how to just get [this arrow back][1].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the notification area options, you can uncheck `Always show all icons and notification on the taskbar` to get your arrow back.

[image: Uncheck Always show all icons and notification on the taskbar]